# How to create a modal popup window with external file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a website and I want to create a modal popup window in JavaScript. The problem is, I want to pull the contents of the window from a separate .html file and not from a hidden div on the page (this is how most of the examples I have seen show you how to do it).

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on how to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Matt D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using jQuery (which you should)

```
var div = $('#myid');  // container for the content

$.get(url)                      // get the content
 .success(function(resp) {      // on success
   $(div)
      .html(resp)               // populate the div
      .dialog({ modal: true }); // and turn it into a dialog
 });
```

NB: this example uses jQuery 1.5's new "deferred" syntax.  If using an earlier function pass the handler as a parameter to `$.get` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the HTML file is on the same domain as the site (because cross-domain requests won't work), you can initiate an Ajax request to retrieve the data and insert it into the containing element.

Although you don't need to use jQuery (or any other library, for that matter) to handle the Ajax request and response, it makes it much easier especially when dealing with cross-browser nuances.

You could do something like this (assuming that myModel has a display of none):

```
// Initiate a request to the HTML file
$.get('url-to-file-.html', function(data) {

  // Insert the returned data into an element with
  // the ID of myModel and then show it.
  $('#myModel').html(data).show();

});
```

Simple example, but that should do it. You can see more in-depth examples of jQuery's [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) on the API page.

Comment: and use jQuery.UI's "dialog" function to turn #myModel into a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe to display another page inside your popup.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's suggestion is a good one. You could also use jQuery's load (http://api.jquery.com/load/) function which will [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the html directly into an element:

```
$(modelContainerId).load(pathToHtml+ " #sectionOfHtml", function (response, status, xhr) {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $(modelContainerId),
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .9,
            color: '#fff',
            top: ($(window).height() - 700) / 2 + 'px',
            left: ($(window).width() - 700) / 2 + 'px',
            width: '700px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    });

    $('.blockOverlay').attr('title', 'Click to unblock').click($.unblockUI);
});
```

Here `.load(pathToHtml+ " #sectionOfHtml"` loads only the id named `#sectionOfHtml` from the loaded html. I used this feature to load different help pages in a context sensitive way.